# Differences of between ''either $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $g(x)=0$ for all $x$'' AND ''for all $x$ either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$''

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Let $f,g$ be two functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Assume for all $x$ $f(x)g(x)=0$, then

**i)** then either $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $g(x)=0$  for all $x$.

**ii)** then for all $x$ either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$.

**My answer is**:Assume for all $x$ the equation $f(x)g(x)=0$ holds. Let $f\left( x\right) =\begin{cases}1, & x=1\\ 0,& x\neq 1\end{cases}$  and $g\left( x\right) =\begin{cases}1, & x=2\\ 0,& x\neq 2\end{cases}$. So, these works for the equation but it doesn't imply that for all $x$, $f(x)$ or for all $x$, $g(x)$ must be zero.

**Can you check that does my answer works *i)* and *ii)*?** And can you explain Differences of between ''either $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $g(x)=0$  for all $x$'' AND ''for all $x$ either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$''?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say either $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ you have to have one of your functions identically zero for all $ x$.

On the other hand  for all $x$ either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$ simply means the  product of your functions must be identically zero.

As you see, the first statement implies the second one but the second does not imply the first one.

Comment: why  the second does not imply the first one, can you give an example?

Comment: in the second statement, I have to I one of my functions identically zero for all $x$, right?

Comment: No that is the first case. An example for the second case is $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $g(x)=1$ otherwise

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between :

> "either $P(x)$ for all $x$ or $Q(x)$ for all $x$" AND "for all $x$ either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$".

Consider :

> "either all (natural) numbers are even or all (natural) numbers are odd" versus "all (natural) numbers are either even or odd".

Comment: I think, there is no any differences:"either all (natural) numbers are even or all (natural) numbers are odd" versus "all (natural) numbers are either even or odd".

Comment: "all (natural) numbers are either even or odd" is TRUE. What about "either all (natural) numbers are even or all (natural) numbers are odd" ? A disjunction is TRUE when at least one of the disjunct is TRUE. It is TRUE that "all (natural) numbers are even" ? It is TRUE that "all (natural) numbers are odd" ?

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments.